# Python write file empty

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script to convert an Intel HEX file to a Verilog mem format.
I can print the strings I want to save OK (eg the read & parse bit's working)  but when I try to write to a file nothing ever appears :(

```
ihexf = open("test.hex","r")
vmemf = open("test.mem","w")

for line in ihexf:
    rlen_s = line[1:3]
    addr_s = line[3:7]
    rtyp_s = line[7:9]
    rlen = int(rlen_s, 16)
    addr = int(addr_s, 16)
    rtyp = int(rtyp_s, 16)
#    print(rlen_s,addr_s,rtyp_s)

    if rtyp == 0:
#        print('@'+addr_s)
        vmemf.write('@'+addr_s+'\n')
        for i in range (0, rlen):
            laddr = addr + i
            val_s = line[9+i*2:9+i*2+2]
            val = int(val_s, 16)
#            print(val_s)
            vmemf.write(val_s+'\n')            
#        print("")
    else:
        print("------- End Of File ------")
ihexf.close()
vmemf.close()
```

My test.hex looks like

```
:20000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FF000000FF000000FF555540FF0A
:20000800155540FF055540FF015540FF005540FF001540FF000540FF000140FF000040FF56
:20001000000040FF000140FF000540FF001540FF005540FF015540FF055540FF155540FF4E
:00000001FF
```

Any clues what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Normally I'd say you forgot to close the file. But you don't forget, so all should be ok. Any chance that you added the close() later and forgot to save?

Comment: Are you sure you are running exactly this code and not some stale version? This code produces a recognizably structured output file.

Comment: I run your code on my machine, it produces a non-empty file.

Comment: Is there a blank line at the end of your script file?

Comment: I wonder if it might help if you opened the file in binary mode.

Comment: The code is exactly what I'm running. I'm using Python 3.4.1 on Windows so I'll trying moving to a linux machine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have closed the file and very importantly that you reposition the file pointer to the start of the file and start reading chunks.

```
ihexf.seek(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - I worked out what was happening (I think!)

Existing code works on linux but not Windows.
On Windows I was seeing the following once the script finished:

```
@0000
@0008
@0010
@0018
------- End Of File ------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Nigel\SkyDrive\Files\python\intexhex2v.py", line 8, in <module>
rlen = int(rlen_s, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''`
```

Looks like things were messing up at the end of the file read.

Adding `break` after the End-Of-File print fixed everything

Thanks